# How to retrieve, store, and update data in Firestore using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to retrieve data (let's say a list of todos) from Firestore and render it to the DOM, but I'm unsure how to properly do this/what the best practice is. Do I retrieve the data from Firestore using useEffect and onSnapshot and store it in state? When adding, deleting, and/or changing data (todos), is it as simple as just using the .add(), .delete(), .update() Firestore methods to update the database, and thus updating the DOM (because of the onSnaphot)?

The code below works, but I'm interested in learning the best way to go about this problem. I heard storing data in state isn't a very good idea so that is another reason I'm asking.

```
const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState([])

useEffect( () => {
    const db = firebase.firestore().collection('todos')

    db.onSnapshot( snapshot => {
        const retrievedTodos = []

        snapshot.forEach( doc => {
            retrievedTodos.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
        })

        setTodos(retrievedTodos)
    })
}, [])


return (
    <div>
        {todos.map( todo => {
            return <TodoItem 
                text={todo.text} 
                key={todo.id} />
        })}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: might get some inspiration here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hooks

Comment: This is a perfectly good method of accomplishing this. When they say don't store data in state, they mean do exactly as you have done, only using state as an intermediary between firestore and your app.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the clarification!